# Hadoop-2.2.0 NammeNode startup issue

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop and facing the following issue while starting NameNode with ./hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode command.

Steps I followed:

```
1. Downloaded Ubuntu13 VM ans installed Java 1.6 and hadoop-2.2.0
2. updated the configuration files 
3. ran this hadoop namenode –format
4. ran this from sbin dir ./hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
```

Error is:

```
2014-01-04 06:55:48,561 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
2014-01-04 06:55:48,565 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
2014-01-04 06:55:48,565 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
2014-01-04 06:55:48,571 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 2.0% max memory = 888.9 MB
2014-01-04 06:55:48,571 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^22 = 4194304 entries
2014-01-04 06:55:48,603 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
2014-01-04 06:55:48,604 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
2014-01-04 06:55:48,604 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
2014-01-04 06:55:48,604 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
2014-01-04 06:55:48,604 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
2014-01-04 06:55:48,604 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: shouldCheckForEnoughRacks  = false
2014-01-04 06:55:48,605 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
2014-01-04 06:55:48,605 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
2014-01-04 06:55:48,616 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = user (auth:SIMPLE)
2014-01-04 06:55:48,617 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
2014-01-04 06:55:48,617 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
2014-01-04 06:55:48,617 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
2014-01-04 06:55:48,621 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
2014-01-04 06:55:48,717 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
2014-01-04 06:55:48,717 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
2014-01-04 06:55:48,717 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 1.0% max memory = 888.9 MB
2014-01-04 06:55:48,717 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2014-01-04 06:55:48,732 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
2014-01-04 06:55:48,738 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
2014-01-04 06:55:48,738 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
2014-01-04 06:55:48,738 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
2014-01-04 06:55:48,740 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
2014-01-04 06:55:48,740 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
2014-01-04 06:55:48,744 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map Namenode Retry Cache
2014-01-04 06:55:48,744 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
2014-01-04 06:55:48,744 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory = 888.9 MB
2014-01-04 06:55:48,744 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^16 = 65536 entries
2014-01-04 06:55:48,768 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /home/user/hadoop2_data/hdfs/namenode/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 12574@ubuntuvm
2014-01-04 06:55:48,785 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50070
2014-01-04 06:55:48,789 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...
2014-01-04 06:55:48,791 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.
2014-01-04 06:55:48,791 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2014-01-04 06:55:48,793 **FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.**
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:684)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1320)
2014-01-04 06:55:48,798 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2014-01-04 06:55:48,803 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ubuntuvm/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue, I tried to google but still didn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your "hadoop namenode -format" didn't take (I assume you've tried hitting that command again and it still doesn't work). When you invoke hadoop namenode -format the user you are running as must have write access to the directories in dfs.data.dir and dfs.name.dir.

By default they are set to

```
${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data
```

and

```
${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/name
```

where hadoop.tmp.dir is another config property that defaults to /tmp/hadoop-${username}.

So by default the hadoop data files are kept under your /tmp directory, which is not that great, especially if you have scripts that can clean out those directories.

Ensure that in core-site.xml you have set your dfs.data.dir and dfs.name.dir to directories that the user who is running hadoop admin commands and starting the hadoop daemons can write to. Then reformat HDFS and try again.